# What's the right way to specialize a template when using "extern template"?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I am hoping someone can point out the correct way to specialize a method in a template class while using "extern template class" and "template class" for explicit instantiation with gnu c++. I've tried to boil down this problem with the simplest example that mimics my real problem.  It appears that declaring "extern template" implies a template instantiation which causes errors when specializing methods.  Given a driver program:

main.cc

```
#include A_H
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    A<int> ai;
    A<long> al;

    std::cout << "ai=" << ai.get() << " al=" << al.get() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And the following implemntation of A

a.h

```
template<typename T>
struct A
{
    int get() const;
};

extern template class A<int>;
extern template class A<long>;
```

a.cc

```
#include "a.h"

template<typename T>
int A<T>::get() const
{
    return 0;
}

template<>
int A<long>::get() const
{
    return 1;
}

template class A<int>;
template class A<long>;
```

I receive the following error when compiling with either, g++ 4.1.2 or 4.4.4

```
 % g++ -Wall -g -D'A_H="a.h"' a.cc main.cc          
a.cc:10: error: specialization of 'int A<T>::get() const [with T = long int]' after instantiation
 %
```

If I comment out the two "extern template" lines in a.h, things compile and work as expected with both compilers.  I assume depending on the existence of an explicit instantiation in the absence of "extern template" is unspecified behavior even in C++0x, otherwise, what's the point of C++0x adding "extern template"?

If I instead implement A as:

a-hack.h

```
template<typename T>
struct A
{
    int get() const;
};

template<typename T>
int A<T>::get() const
{
    return 0;
}

template<>
inline
int A<long>::get() const
{
    return 1;
}

extern template class A<int>;
extern template class A<long>;
```

a-hack.cc

```
#include "a-hack.h"

template class A<int>;
template class A<long>;
```

and compile again, this works as expected

```
% g++ -Wall -g -D'A_H="a-hack.h"' a-hack.cc main.cc
% ./a.out 
ai=0 al=1
```

However, in my real world example, this causes a program crash with g++ 4.1.2 (while working for g++ 4.4.4).  I have not narrowed down the exact cause of the crash (segmentation fault).  It only appears as if the stack pointer is corrupted within what would be the call to A<>::get().

I realize that explicit template instantiation is non-standard at this point, but would anyone expect what I've done above to work?  If not, what is the correct way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: c++0x removed extern template, because it was too difficult to implement, no?

Comment: @VJo: `export` was removed. `extern` (for templates) was added.

Comment: @James Must be something new, as I haven't seen exported templates so far

Comment: @VJo:  Yes, it's new in C++0x, though some compilers have supported it as an extension for some time.  Visual C++ has had it since 2005.

Comment: @VJo, @James: James' last reply [20:44] seems to conflate two different things (where his comment of [18:40] was clearer). `export` templates were implemented by EDG, standardized in C++03, and removed in C++11 after no other compiler vendor ever picked them up. `extern` templates have been supported by EDG/GCC/IBM/Metrowerks/MSVC since 2003 (source: [N1448](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2003/n1448.pdf), see also [N1987](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n1987.htm)), but were standardized only in C++11 (similar to what happened with `long long`).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
extern template class A<long>;
```

This line says that `A<long>` is to be explicitly instantiated *according to the definitions the compiler has already seen*.  When you add a specialization later, you break that meaning.

Add a declaration of your specialization to the header file.

```
template <typename T> struct A { /*...*/ };
template<> int A<long>::get() const;
extern template class A<int>;
extern template class A<long>;
```

In general, it's best to put as many specialization declarations as possible in the same header file as the primary template, to reduce surprises for the compiler about which declaration should be used for any particular instantiation.

---

Notice that the `extern template` declaration isn't necessary if you're dealing with a single template entity (as opposed to this case, where we have to instruct the compiler about both the *class* `A<long>` and the *function* `A<long>::get()`). If you want to specialize a function template in another translation unit, it suffices to write just `template<>`.

```
template<typename T> int freeGet() { return 0; }  // you can even add "inline" here safely!
template<> int freeGet<long>();  // this function is not inline (14.7.3/12)
```

But you must have the `<>` there. If you omit the `<>`, the declaration turns into an explicit instantiation of the *default* implementation (`return 0`), which is likely not what you wanted! Even if you add `extern`, the compiler is allowed to *inline* that default implementation; if your code unexpectedly breaks when you pass `-O2`, you might have accidentally omitted the `<>` somewhere.

Comment: That was it, thanks!  Do you have an idea as to why it is necessary for "extern template" or its dependents to care about the existence of a specialization?  The "name" of the method is int A<long>::get() const regardless, and the explicit instantiation could ensure that only the correct definition of that is available at link time.

Comment: @Roland In general, you could do something like `template <> class A<long> { int iHaveNoGetFunctionAtAll(); };` such that in fact a `A<long>::get()` function does not even exist! This might be a reason why the compiler requires to declare the specilization before applying "extern template" with it.

Comment: Excellent answer, but could you add whether it is legal to combine lines 2 and 4 of your example into the single line `extern template<> int A<long>::get() const;`? That's the question I came here in hopes of answering.

Comment: @Quuxplusone: Not in that syntax.  If you want an explicit specialization (which you must define), use the `template<> int A<long>:get() const;` version.  If you want an explicit instantiation (defined via the template), don't put any brackets after `template`: `template int A<long>::get() const;` (add `extern` in front to make it not a definition).

Comment: What if I want an explicit extern *specialization*, but want to express that concept in one single declaration? Impossible?

Comment: @Quuxplusone: I don't think I understand.  Probably just ask a new question.

Comment: @aschepler I'll just edit your answer, and then you can change it if I'm wrong. ;)

Comment: @Quuxplusone: Your example is legal, but the first line doesn't do anything.  Why do you want to declare an explicit specialization, which is normally used for a definition different from the template, when you're just going to use the original template anyway?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50640/discussion-between-quuxplusone-and-aschepler)

Comment: Jeez. It is bizarre to me that the `extern template /* member-function-specialization */` syntax is *legal* but doesn't do anything like what you'd expect, and *behaves differently under different optimization modes*. At least the "specialization...after instantiation" compile error will usually catch this, since using `extern` probably means you're going to define the member-function later. Thanks for explaining a really (pointlessly) tricky bit of the language.

Comment: "...according to the definitions the compiler has already seen" (...), so just pre-declare it. I am not knew to templates nor externs but the conciseness and clarity of this sentence added something I was missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Adding this answer to address the question in the title (template instantiation, and not necessarily template *method* instantiation).

This much resembles function declaration/definition.

- Explicit instantiation declaration: `extern template class` is a declaration and should generally go in the header.
- Explicit instantiation definition: `template class` is a definition and should generally go in the cpp.
- No code is generated in object files following the declaration.
- Code is generated in the object file of the cpp that contained the definition.
- Without explicit instantiation, implicit instantiation will take place when the template is actually used. This will happen in every compilation unit (object file) that uses the template.
- Implicit instantiation won't take place if a declaration was encountered. This is the gist of this mechanism - avoid object code duplication caused by implicit instantiation that happened because the compiler didn't trust that there's a single compilation unit in charge of instantiating the template.

More info [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template).

Comment: Do you mean that `template class` should go in the .cpp file associated with the declaration, or in a cpp file that uses the template somewhere else?

Comment: https://arne-mertz.de/2019/02/extern-template-reduce-compile-times/ has an example of what you mean I think, and it's supposed to go in the associated .cpp, rather than a cpp that just uses it, thanks

Comment: Yes you got it right - it should usually go in the associated cpp. This was the intention of the answer, if it wasn't clear from there.