# erroneous explicit template specialization of variable template in gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, c++14, c++17

// i.h

```
template<int> extern int const i;
```

// i.cpp

```
#include "i.h"
template<> extern int constexpr i<0> = 42;
```

// main.cpp

```
#include "i.h"
int main()
{
  return i<0>;
}
```

In C++14/17 mode this returns 42 with clang, but is an error with gcc: "explicit template specialization cannot have a storage class".

Is this a bug in gcc?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the right way to specialize a template when using "extern template"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5356269/whats-the-right-way-to-specialize-a-template-when-using-extern-template)
The specialization is part of the interface - you can't hide it away in the .cpp file like this.
For example, a specialization could be to sfinae away or static_assert on some types T, and that needs to be known in client code.

Comment: No, sorry, that's a completely different issue.

Comment: Hmm. Could you show the initial template declaration? Did you mean to write contexpr in the .cpp file and const in the .h file?

Comment: Hmm. Do you want an explicit instantantiation or setting linkage ? note that global template names have external linkage by default ... in other words, can you explain what's the final intent ?

Comment: @JohanLundberg The code above is complete. And yes, I mean everything I wrote. There are no typos.

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes I want both. The primary variable template must be declared extern since it is const and I don't want initializers in the header file (just like with ordinary "extern int const i;"). Instead I want specialization definitions in some source file. Why? If I have them in the header file all clients that include the header file must be recompiled if a definition changes. I don't want that. But if definitions are in a source file I could easily change them without the need to recompile the whole world (again, just like with ordinary "extern int const i;").

Comment: ok, got the problem now ... posting an answer

Answer (score 2):

There is a rather simple solution to this whole issue. Please additionally see [this](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/embed/?place=forum%2Fstd-discussion&showsearch=true&showpopout=true&parenturl=https%3A%2F%2Fisocpp.org%2Fforums%2Fiso-c-standard-discussion#!topic/std-discussion/RBTtlBjxxgU) post on the ISO C++ Standard - Discussion forum and the reply from Richard Smith.

1.
`extern` must not be specified in an explicit specialization

So to answer the original question: **no, it is not a bug in gcc**, it is correct to report an error (as Massimiliano Janes already answered).

In contrast **clang actually has a bug here** (as Massimiliano Janes already guessed) because `extern` is accepted. Maybe clang accepts it silently because it is the same as that of the primary template.

2.
Theoretically (according to the standard) the solution is to drop `extern` because with templates linkage is by name and so the specialization 'inherits' the linkage of the primary template (again see Massimiliano Janes' answer)

But in practice **it does not work because both compilers are incorrect** here and the explicit specialization incorrectly has internal linkage instead of the linkage of the primary template which is external.

3.
In summary:

gcc never compiles which is correct in (1) but incorrect in (2).
clang compiles in (1) which is incorrect but does not compile in (2) which is also incorrect.

I'll file a bug report for clang. If someone is interested please feel free to file a bug for gcc. I won't do this because (unfortunately) I can't use gcc in my development environment Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

> The primary variable template must be declared extern since it is const and I don't want initializers in the header file (just like with ordinary "extern int const i;"). Instead I want specialization definitions in some source file.

the solution should be to drop the 'extern' in the specialization.

because

> [declarations/specifiers-7.1.1]A storage-class-specifier shall not be specified in an explicit specialization

the rationale being that all specializations should have the same linkage ( see for example [defect report 605](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#605)). So, it seems clang's wrong here.

Anyway, given that compilers turn out behaving wildly on this, a workaround could be something like

```
// i.h
template<int I> struct i_impl{ static const int value; };
template<int I> int const i = i_impl<I>::value;

// i.cpp
#include <i.h>
template<> const int i_impl<0>::value = 42;
```

Comment: "the solution should be to drop the 'extern' in the specialization" But if it is dropped then i<0> has internal linkage just like ordinary const declared variables. As a result there is an undefined reference to i<0> in main(). That's not what I want. Additionally the linkage of the specialization i<0> would be different from the primary variable template which violates the rationale you mention. So dropping extern is not a solution.

Comment: Conceptually the variable template i is just a "templated" extern int const and its definition in some source must have the extern specifier if it is not previously declared (in that case the extern specifier could be dropped). In other words the specialization i<0> with the extern specifier seems totally reasonable to me. But 7.1.1 (or 10.1.1 in C++17) contradicts so unfortunately it seems clang is wrong (even if compiled with -pedantic-errors) and gcc is right. Or does the standard have a defect here?

Comment: And finally the latest MSVC reports the error "'i<0>': an object of const-qualified type must be initialized" in main.cpp. This seems completely wrong to me since i is declared extern. So three different compilers give three different results. That's not really good.

Comment: @Rakete1111 it is, for an explicit instantantiation the extern should precede template ...

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes Oh gosh, that's so true. Can't believe I missed that, thanks :P

Comment: @xy take a look at the defect report, *in theory*, specializations should have the same linkage of the primary template; otherwise, given the standard quote 7.1.1 there should be no way of specifying the linkage of the specialization

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes That means two opposite things: it should be declared extern to have the same linkage as the primary template (and in this case it must be declared extern because otherwise it does not have external linkage), and at the same time it must not be declared extern due to 7.1.1. That's impossible. This seems like a defect to me. 7.1.1 should make an exception for variable templates declared extern because otherwise they are useless if specializations are to be defined in a different source file. What do you think?

Comment: One more thought: the example is really just a simple "templated" constant variable declared extern which exist since the initial standard. The fact that three very common compilers "behave wildly" on this shows that the standard is somewhat unclear and ambiguous in this case.

Comment: the situation is pretty clear standard-wise, you specify linkage on the primary template, specializations follows. The reason why compilers are not consistent on this is probably because before variable templates this was seldom an issue to care about.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it is clear standard-wise. What do you mean by "specializations follows"? Do you mean specializations inherit (or should inherit) the linkage specifier of the primary template? I ask because this is not the case here. If extern is not specified on the specialization it has internal linkage and not the linkage of the primary template, which is extern. In short: it does not inherit extern.

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes The workaround you mention does not work, neither with clang nor gcc. This is because i_impl<0>::value is specified constexpr and hence has internal linkage. This results in undefined reference to it in main().

Comment: as I got it, specializations should 'inherit' linkage from the primary template ( see the defect report resolution I linked to: templates have external linkage by default, and specializations (implicit or explicit) of templates with internal linkage should be distinct for each translation unit ).

Comment: @xy just tryed it and the workaround works ok on my clang copy; moreover, it's not true that constexpr implies internal linkage ... this would contradict the aforementioned defect resolution

Comment: What's your clang? I used the online Wandbox and the latest clang/gcc trunk. You can try for yourself. Your workaround works if you specify const instead of constexpr. This implies that constexpr implies internal linkage. Or are both compilers buggy?

Comment: @xy apple clang v800.0.42.1 works fine ( as it should be, as far as I know ); anyway, just replace constexpr with const; it's clear that compilers behaves inconsistently concerning variable template linkage, so if you still have doubts you should ask clang/gcc support forums/mailing list for more info.

Comment: Yes, of course I could do that. But the specific reason why I specify constexpr and not const in the definition of i<0> is to avoid dynamic initialization. If i is a literal type that has a constexpr constructor (instead of a stupid int that I chose only for simplicity) then it is initialized by constant initialization and not by dynamic initialization. Replacing constexpr with const does not guarantee that.

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes I think I know why your clang compiles it: do you compile in C++14 mode? In that mode it works fine. But in C++17 mode i_impl<0>::value with the specifier constexpr is an inline variable and has internal linkage.

Comment: @xy yep that makes sense :)

Answer (score 0):

According to [N4340](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4340.html):

> A storage-class-specifier othe than thread_local shall not be
>   specified in an explicit specialization (14.7.3) or an explicit
>   instantiation (14.7.2) directive.

So, This happens with the `extern` specifier. Just remove any storage specifier on the specialization.In your code remove `extern` specifier. Such as :

```
template<> 
int constexpr i<0> = 42;
```

Comment: This is no solution. Without the extern specifier i<0> has internal linkage (see my first comment on the first answer).

Comment: @xy this *is* a solution standard-wise ( although it's almost identical to the other answer ), sadly it's not in practice due to compiler inertia ...

Comment: What do you mean? Do you mean if extern is not specified on the specialization then i<0> has external linkage standard-wise? Do you know where the proof is in the standard? I ask because if that is really true then both clang and gcc are buggy since both report "undefined reference to i<0> in main()" in that case.

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes Just for your information: I could answer my own question with additional insight from a member of the committee (see below)

Comment: @rsp Just for your information: I could answer my own question with additional insight from a member of the committee (see above)